# Conditionally load jquery throbber plugin

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-plugins, throbber

I have the code below that shows a throbber and makes a getJSON call to an MVC action when the user changes an entry in a select.  This all works great except there is a default -- select -- element in the list for which I don't want the getJSON to run.

However, I can't work out how to apply conditional logic to hooking this event.  The conditional logic is shown as the `if(selectedValue == -1)`  But the throbber still runs as I've hooked it in the first line.  I've tried removing the first line that hooks the change event and use $.throbberShow(..) inline just prior to the getJSON call but for some reason this doesn't show the throbber.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
$("#selectlist").throbber("change", { ajax: false, image: "images/ajax-loader-line.gif" });

                $("#selectlist").change(

                    function () {
                        var selectedValue = $("#selectlist").val();

                        if (selectedValue != -1) {
                            //Tried doing $.throbberShow(...) here without success
                            $.getJSON("/Candidate/GetAddress", { id: selectedValue }, function (data, textStatus) {
                                if (textStatus == "success") {
                                    $("#selectlist").val(data.Line1)
                                    $("#selectlist").val(data.Line2)
                                    $("#selectlist").val(data.Line3)
                                    $("#selectlist").val(data.Town)
                                }
                                $.throbberHide();
                            });
                        }

                    }
                );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more a hack than a solution as throbber doesn't support conditions but this should work:

```
$("#selectlist").throbber("change", { ajax: false, image: "images/ajax-loader-line.gif", delay: "500" });

$("#selectlist").change(
  function () {
    var selectedValue = $("#selectlist").val();
    if (selectedValue != -1) {
      $.getJSON("/Candidate/GetAddress", { id: selectedValue }, function (data, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus == "success") {
          $("#selectlist").val(data.Line1)
          $("#selectlist").val(data.Line2)
          $("#selectlist").val(data.Line3)
          $("#selectlist").val(data.Town)
        }
        $.throbberHide();
      });   
    } else {
      $.throbberHide();
    }
  }
);
```